# Django - Model Schema for a Messaging app

Tags: django, database, model, schema

I've found a lot of examples of django message apps, but not the one I actually want.
I want to have messages between users (1-1) and a "inbox" to manage them. The inbox should be able to group the messages in some sort of a conversation, so you can read the whole conversation history.
What would be a appropriate way to do this? I was thinking about making a Inbox Manager for the message objects like that:

```
class Inbox(models.Manager):

    # Get conversations between users
    # Handle reading, sending, etc

class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'))
    sender = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='sent', verbose_name=_("Sender"))
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='received', verbose_name=_("Recipient"))

    objects = Inbox
```

For anyone who is thinking, why I'd want a inbox.. I want to be able to use the app like that later:

```
Inbox.send_message(to=some_user, message="Hey there, whats up??")
```

I'm open to better ideas on how to reach my goal.

Comment: One user one inbox or multiple inboxes are available? You need to be more specific about the requirements.

Comment: Just one... We just need it to manage the messages

Comment: What kind of management? If one user has only one `Inbox`, then isn't `User` and `Inbox` the same thing? If you really want something to do it, why not creating a model `Inbox` that has `OneToOneField` to a `User`?

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a model.. I just want a central way to send, read, list, delete (manage) messages.

Comment: If you want that then you must define a normal class with a bunch of classmethods: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod. But if you want to represent `A user has an Inbox that he owns and it could manage his own mails` relationship(remember you are using a relational database), how can you do it without a model?

Comment: Well, an alternative is to have your own `User` model and have a bunch of methods like `send_message` in the model. Then you can do `user1.send_message()`, `user1.list_messages()`, `user1.delete_message()`, etc. Then I don't see the point of having `Inbox` anymore. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: I think I will use a manager and do something like this: `Messages.objects.send_message(from, to, message)` or `Messages.objects.get_conversation(partner1, partner2)`. What do you think?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, model managers are used as an interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. `send_message` doesn't have anything to do with query, so it might confuse other programmers who read your code. It's of course doable, but I wouldn't use a manager. `send_message` might as well be just a method itself, doesn't have to belong to any class. Why not create a python module with all these methods and import it?